# Anime/cartoon where the main cast uses 2 golden coins to summon a mech from the sky

Tags: story-identification, anime, cartoon, mecha

I remember watching it on tv the 2 protagonists went to an arcade and they insert the coins into an arcade machine and this would activate the mech. They also changed the cast 3 times so I think the show has multiple seasons.

Answer (score 1):

### *NG Knight Lamune & 40* (1990)

Could this be a slightly mixed up memory of [*NG Knight Lamune & 40*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NG_Knight_Ramune_%26_40)?

From Wikipedia:

> Tama-Q- (Voiced by Chie Koujiro) A hand sized advisor robot that can summon the guardian knights if Lamune drop coins into the slot on his head.

See 15:08 at https://www.crunchyroll.com/ng-knight-lamune-40/episode-8-lost-lost-in-the-horramid-786159